# Rename multiple files in sequence through command line

Tags: windows, command-line, rename

I have 9873 files in a folder on hard-drive that are named as

- `myname-script.sql.001`
- `myname-script.sql.002`
- and so on

Now I need to rename these files to

- `myname-script.001.sql`
- `myname-script.002.sql`
- and so on

I want to name them all at once through command line.

Comment: Why must you use the command line? What's wrong with using a rename program; there are many that do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the program...I saw a couple of people doing it in one go through command line....so I was wondering if there was a single command to do this...

Comment: Can this be done via a script rather then command line?

Comment: yes it can...I was hoping to get a command line...but seems like it's more feasible using script

Comment: Answer posted in 6 lines of vbscript - you would be hard pressed to do it in command prompt using 1 line of code without a 3rd party app or pre-writing functions in powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vbscript to rename

> Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>
> set oFldr = fso.getfolder("C:\file\path")
>
> for each ofile in oFldr.Files
>
> splited = Split(ofile.Name, ".", -1, 1)
>
> ofile.name = splited(0) & "." & splited(2) & "." & splited(1)
>
> Next

This script will split your file name via the `.` and then re-arrange it to swap the 2nd and 3rd extensions

Comment: I am writing my own script and will post if anybody wants..Thanks..

Comment: Always best practice to answer your own question if you find the solution outside the answers provided and to upvote any answers that were helpful in being able to develop your own script

Comment: Ok Sir...Will do

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far? You should really do some research into the possible solutions and try a few things.

I also think this question may be better suited to `StackOverflow.` Anyway, I've modified a `VBScript` that I wrote a while ago that achieves what you want. I'm very much a VBScript novice, so please forgive the long-windedness of it. I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but it does definitely work. The script assumes that the files will be encountered in order so you might run into some issues.

I have made the script available through my `Google Drive` account:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-7FwCWf15oGd2R0R1RMaHdmRFk/edit?usp=sharing

You'll only have to change the file path in order for the script to work. The `VBScript` code in case the file doesn't work:

```
Dim sName
Dim fso
Dim folder
Dim count
count = 1

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set folder = fso.GetFolder("Your folder path")

For Each file In folder.Files   
    If count < 10 Then
        file.Name = "myname-script.00" + CStr(count) + ".sql"
    End If

    If count > 9 And count < 100 Then
        file.Name = "myname-script.0" + CStr(count) + ".sql"
    End If

    If count > 99 And count < 10000 Then
        file.Name = "myname-script." + CStr(count) + ".sql"
    End If
    count = count + 1
Next
```

Comment: This is what I have tried so far:
    1. ren *.* *.sql;
    2. ren *.^sql.* *.sql;
    3. ren *.^sql.* .sql;
    4. ren *^(.sql).* *.sql;

Comment: Not sure about that. Check the script in my answer. You'll just have to change one line (the path) for it to work. Test it on a few files to see if it actually works.

Comment: I can do it through coding...but I was wondering if anyone has a command line option for the same...Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: Please post answers here and not in a link to a different website to avoid link rot

Comment: @Ani I just realised the code in the linked file is slightly off. You'll have to move the count = count + 1 line just before the "Next" keyword.

Comment: No problem...I am writing my customized script....I got the gist...thanks.

Comment: @Ani No worries :)

Comment: This will lose all pre-defined ordering and replace it with the count from the script correct?

Comment: Not sure. OP said he was re-writing the script to meet his needs. My script just pushed him in the right direction. Your solution is much neater.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple as pure `cmd.exe` (batch). I haven't tested, but I think I've got it correct.

As a long one liner from the command line:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %A in ('dir /b /a-d *.sql*^|findstr "\.sql\.[^.]*$"') do @for %B in ("%~nA") do @ren "%A" "%~nB%~xA%~xB"
```

As a batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d *.sql*^|findstr "\.sql\.[^.]*$"'
) do for %%B in ("%%~nA") do ren "%%A" "%%~nB%%~xA%%~xB"
```

Answer (score -2):

You could use a loop and some cut and paste strategy, like this:

```
for i in `ls myname-script.sql.*` ; do j=`ls $i | cut -d '.' -f2` ; k=`ls $i | cut -d '.' -f3` ; mv $i myname-script.$k.$j ; done
```

Comment: The OP is on Windows though. Also note that the call to `ls` is unnecessary. And please, check your formatting before posting. Code should be indented by 4 spaces.